# How many CCs is online play?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 8, when you play online, what CC level are you playing on? 50, 100, 150, or 200CC?

Essentially, I'm trying to determine what single player speeds online play is closest to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just depends on your opponents. The CC gauge is to measure AI difficulty, so it wouldn't really be possible to slap a CC number onto every random player you race.

Comment: CC also changes the speed at which you run the races, making the races harder.

Comment: Speed is the main point of it, as it refers to the size of the engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8#Online), it appears to be based off the your/your opponents VR (Versus Ranking):

> Between 1000 and over 4000 VR when playing Worldwide or Regional VS. Race, players race at 100cc, and starting at over 5000 VR, players race at 150cc.

A few GameFAQ threads also discuss this, such as [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/700050-mario-kart-8/69450050), though they state at around 3000 VR is when you start seeing changes:

> At 3000 VR ish I started getting put into 150cc games.

Another [GameFAQ](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/700050-mario-kart-8/69492275):

> After hitting 3000 and being placed in a room with all players being 3000+, it's 150CC. Before 3000, it's 100CC.

It looks like the starting CC is 100.  And from there, it increases depending on the VR of everyone.

Comment: Though with Mario Kart 8 DX on Switch there is an added random chance for 200cc or Mirror as well. The recent patch actually reduced the frequency of this chance. `“Worldwide” and “Regional” modes add players to Mirror and 200cc matches less often.` - [Version 1.1 update notes](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26098/)